# How to form post (validate and update my database) - controller syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've managed to retrieve and display the Auth user profile details in my profile view, but I'm missing something (or a few things) to do the actual update.

Can you help?

profile.blade.view

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Update your user profile</div>

            <div class="panel-body">                    

            {!! Form::open(array('action' => array('HomeController@postProfileEdit', $user->id))) !!}

            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('firstName', 'First name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('firstName', $userinfo->first_name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

            {!! Form::label('lastName', 'Last name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('lastName', $userinfo->last_name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class'=>'btn primary']) !!}
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('profile', 'HomeController@profile');
Route::post('profile', 'HomeController@postProfileEdit');
```

HomeController.php - profile()

```
/**
 * Show the application user profile to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function profile()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $userinfo = \Auth::user();

    return view('profile')->with(['user' => $user])->with('userinfo', $userinfo);
}
```

HomeController.php - postProfileEdit(Request $request)

```
/**
 * Store updates to user profile.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function postProfileEdit(Request $request)
{

    $userinfo = Request::all();
    $user = new User;
    $user->exists = true;
    $user->id = Auth::user();
    $user->first_name = $userinfo['firstName'];
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->action('HomeController@profile');

    //return Response::make('Your user profile was updated successfully!');
}
```

requests.php - for validation

```
abstract class Request extends FormRequest {

/**
 * The URI to redirect to if validation fails
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirect = 'users/create';

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'firstName' => 'required|min:3',
        'lastName' => 'required|min:3'
    ];
}

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}

}
```

I'm getting:

FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 170: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\updateProfile' not found

I know the $updateProfile = new updateProfile;

line is wrong, I'm just not sure what is wrong.

Hope this makes sense.

---

Update:

I changed the class from updateProfile to User (name of the model where I'm doing the change) in HomeController.php

Now I get the following message:

ErrorException in HomeController.php line 174: Undefined variable: userinfo

I'm not sure I can use userinfo from profile.blade.view (see above).

---

Update

I was able to make it work (or not get an error) by fixing 
HomeController@postProfileEdit (post), and return to HomeController@profile (get) when done. But apparently, the save did not get done because even though I changed the first_name value, it stays the same when I go back to HomeController@profile (where first_name is retrieved and displayed).

Comment: Is it displaying any error?
is it getting the route right?

Comment: @DaniloKobold Yes, sorry, I'm getting: FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 170: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\updateProfile' not found . I know the $updateProfile = new updateProfile; line is wrong, I'm just not sure what is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @jedrzej.kurylo's answer.

I have to assume the `updateProfile` is an Eloquent Model found in the `app` directory:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class updateProfile extends Model {
    ...
}
```

Notice the `namespace` declaration at the top of the file? Next, consider the namespace your `HomeController.php` file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

By default, when constructing a class in Laravel, it looks in the current namespace of the controller you're working with. In this case, its trying to find a class `updateProfile` that is in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, which we know doesn't exist.

There are two ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. First, use a `use` statement at the top of your controller for each `Model` you're including.

```
use App\updateProfile;
...
```

Secondly, specify the namespace while declaring the class:

```
$updateProfile = new \App\updateProfile;
```

Either method should clear the error for you.

Comment: You found my problem, updateProfile is just a random name I chose and I realize that it doesn't make sense. As you can see, not sure what i'm doing. I'm trying to update the users table (User model), so changed it accordingly. Now i'm not sure how to pass the form data from my view to my controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\updateProfile' not found
```

This error means that Laravel is looking for *updateProfile* class in current *App\Http\Controllers* namespace but cannot find it. I guess that class is in different namespace so you need to add *use* statement at the beginning of the HomeController file, e.g.:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Some\Namespace\updateProfile;
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I came up with the name updateProfile, it's not defined anywhere. I changed it to User as this is the name of the model for the table (users) i'm updating.